# multicollinearity resulting in high variance

Tags: cart, multicollinearity, bias-variance-tradeoff

Section 8.7.1 of Elements of Statistical Learning talks about high variance in a classification tree due to high correlation between features. What is the intuition behind this? I would think that high correlation between, say two of your features, features is just like having one less feature. How would that result in overfitting / high variance?

Comment: Exactly, whose variance do you refer to? For example, we can say "variance of sample mean", "variance of estimated regression coefficient"...

Comment: As far as I understand it is the variance of the estimates produced by the model across various samples, as in the context of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff

Comment: Sorry, the link says it belongs to machine learning. If you labeled your question as machine learning, I would not involve in this question, because I never studied machine learning. BTW, "The variance is an error from sensitivity to small fluctuations in the training set." confused me more.

Answer (score 1):

First, some definitions. Consider outcome variable, $Y$, and predictors, $X_1, \ldots, X_p$. The regression tree algorithm iteratively splits the units $i = 1, \ldots, n$ into subgroups based on predictor values. Every split creates two subgroups, called nodes, and any unsplit node is called terminal. For unit $i$ in terminal node $t$, where $N_t$ represents the set of units in $t$, the tree-predicted value for unit $i$ is $\hat{Y}_i = \frac{1}{|N_t|}\sum_{i \in N_t} Y_i$. At each iteration, the deviance for the tree $T$, dev($T$) $ = \sum_i\left(\hat{Y}_i - Y_i\right)^2$, is determined before splitting. Then, every possible split on every variable is considered, and the split that results in the largest decrease in deviance is selected. Typically smoothing is imposed via cost-complexity pruning by adding a term to the deviance that is something like $\lambda |T|$, where $|T|$ is the number of terminal nodes in $T$, and $\lambda$ is a tuning-parameter selected, for example, by cross-validation.

Now, back to your question. What is the intuition for why trees with highly correlated predictors are more variable than trees with, say, uncorrelated predictors? This has to do with the splitting at each iteration. If two predictors, let's say $X_1$ and $X_2$ are highly correlated, then it won't make much difference in terms of reduction in deviance which one is selected. In the raw sample, it may be that $X_1$ is selected as the first split (with $X_2$ a very close second because of the high correlation). Now consider a bootstrap sample of the data. It would be easy to imagine that in the bootstrap sample the balance shifts so that the first split now favors $X_2$ instead of $X_1$, with $X_1$ a close second. These splits then have consequences for all subsequent splits made by the algorithm and end up with trees that look quite different, even if predictions are not that different.

Whereas, if the variables were uncorrelated, it is less likely that a minor perturbation to the data will cause a major shift in the order in which variables are split upon. The caveat is that single trees are highly variable no matter the correlation structure. This is why bagging, boosting, and random forests are so useful. You can read more about those methods in ESL as well.

Just noticed you asked about classification trees and I responded in terms of regression trees. The answer is still relevant; you would need to use a different deviance function for classification though like Gini index or cross entropy.

Comment: Thanks for this write-up! I was thinking along similar lines, but a key point: "balance shifts so that the first split now favors X2 instead of X1" is what I'm stuck on. If the predictors are highly correlated, then while splitting on X2 or X1 would give similar reduction in deviance, they would also result in _similar_ trees precisely _because_ they are correlated. For example, if we are classifying dogs vs cats and using size + weight features (correlated), then whether we split on weight or on height (based on minor fluctuations in the data) it would result in a similar split.

Comment: Right, but similar is not identical. Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly related and correlated at .8. Then $X_1$ accounts for only 64% of the variation in $X_2$. Predictions based on $X_2$ will tend to be similar to those based on $X_1$, but may differ in important ways. Over the course of all the splits in a tree, especially if there are multiple correlated variables, the variability can be substantial. To get hands on intuition I'd suggest playing around with some simple simulated data sets and looking at bootstrap estimates of variability.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this as you suggest! I'm getting a little bit more intuition...if your predictors are more somewhat correlated, it is more likely that trees built from different bootstrap samples would split on different features first even with minor differences in the sampled data. On the other hand, with perfect correlation it wouldn't matter at all. Intuitively, it wouldn't make sense for variance to increase with correlation but suddenly drop off at perfect correlation. So I expect highest variance to be somewhere in the middle, between zero and perfect correlation.

Answer (score 1):

In their example,they have one determining feature (x1) and each of the five features has high correlation to the others.

The correlation means that lots of different splits will work on the (small) training data (not just splitting on x1). However, they won't work on the test data.( If the features were perfectly correlated, it would not matter)